# WordPress alert bar is in the wrong location on page for plugin

Tags: plugins

I have several pages within my WordPress plugin. However, one page (PHP file) has an alert bar in the wrong location. I'm guessing it's a missing div issue?

https://prnt.sc/rwxyju

Comment: Why a downvote? I'm just asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have some unbalanced DIVs on that page.

Get the page source into an editor that will format the code and highlight the various DIVs.

If you format the code, that will give you a hint of where the unbalance is.